# Single word for 'lucid exposition'

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word (noun/adjective) that means the same as 'lucid exposition' or 'clear explanation'?

Perhaps, a lucid exposition of a difficult or dense topic. As an example:

> Judt's book, Postwar, provides a lucid exposition of Europe after World War Two.

Comment: No. What made you think there could be?

Answer (score 1):

[coherency](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/coherency?s=t) - (def. 2) logical interconnection; overall sense or understandability

Answer (score 0):

**comprehensible**  ([TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/comprehensible)

> Readily comprehended or understood; intelligible.

Answer (score 0):

Howsabout ***Elucidation***?  From the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[elucidation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/elucidation)***
>
> NOUN
>
> Explanation that makes something clear; clarification.
>
> *‘work that led to the elucidation of the structure of proteins’*

Comment: Except that when people use words like "elucidation" you know that they're trying to obscure something.

Comment: @HotLicks -- Perhaps, but the OP asked for a single word that means "clear explanation" so perhaps they're trying to be ironic in their ofuscation?  8^)